# Setting Bootstrap's Custom File Input Cursor to Pointer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap 4 [Custom File Chooser](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#file-browser) and I modified it to make the Browse "button" appears on the left. This is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="custom-file">
    <input id="application-resume" class="custom-file-input" type="file">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="application-resume">
        Choose file (pdf, docx, doc, odt)
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Disabling the default Browse pseudo element */
.custom-file-label::after {
    content: none;
} 

.custom-file-input:lang(en) ~ .custom-file-label::after {
    content: none;
}

/* Overriding Bootstrap's Custom File classes */
.custom-file {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}

.custom-file-input {
    cursor: inherit !important;
}

.custom-file-label {
    cursor: inherit !important;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0.75rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

.custom-file-label::before {
    content: "Browse";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 2.25rem;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    margin-right: 0.25rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    border-right: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: 0.25rem 0 0 0.25rem;
}

:lang(en) .custom-file-input ~ .custom-file-label::before {
    content: "Browse";
}

.custom-file-input:focus ~ .custom-file-label::before {
    border-color: #80bdff;
}

.input-group > .custom-file:not(:last-child) .custom-file-label::before {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.was-validated .custom-file-input:valid ~ .custom-file-label::before, .custom-file-input.is-valid ~ .custom-file-label::before {
    border-color: inherit;
}

.was-validated .custom-file-input:invalid ~ .custom-file-label::before, .custom-file-input.is-invalid ~ .custom-file-label::before {
    border-color: inherit;
}
```

So everything looks perfect, except that the `cursor: pointer;` works as expected on Firefox (cursor appears as a pointer on whole custom-file component), but not on both Chrome and Opera the cursor appears as default on the 1/4 of the component and as a pointer on the rest:

[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UssqB.jpg)

I don't understand why this is happening since I have all the elements of the custom file component (parent div, input and label) having `cursor: pointer;` in CSS (`cursor: inherited;` for child elements).

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: first to do: check through inspect element (on Chrome at least) whether browser respect your css or just throwing in some default.. though [MDN says chrome support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) it, i'm afraid they had some browser-specific styling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try text-indent: -999px; for the input[type="file"], it will solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you Mohammed it works perfectly on all my browser, 3-point shot made ;)

Comment: Woho, glad that it worsk ;)

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue and i fixed with the below code

```
.custom-file-input {
  z-index: -1;
}

.custom-file-label {
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```